# Mid Side monitoring on PCM-D50

Tags: mid-side, monitoring, field-recording, diy

Hi,

I've been recording M/S since a year or two and am very happy with my setup so far.
My MKH's feed into a SQN4iia and i record on my PCM-D50. Unfortunately, the D50 doesn't have a MS matrix so i always listen to the SQN headphone outputs. This works great most of the time, but sometimes i get overloads when my setttings are either a bit to hot or something wonderful, but unexpected, happens.

Now of course i can pay better attention on my levels or drag around a ms/matrix box, but maybe somebody knows a way to create a small m/s-circuit, that can be placed between my headphone and D50 output? I'm thinking a simple but sturdy mini-jack in/out cable with the matrix in between the connectors.

Any ideas? Is this at all possible or will i lose a lot of output, increase noise?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesent the mixer have direct outs and four inputs?
just use the direct outs to feed th d50 and then return the out from the d50 to the remaining two inputs on the mixer and monitor it that way.
if possible all you need are a few cables.

Comment: oh wow i never thought of that, haha. how brilliantly simple. i'll check and post my experiences.. 

Comment: well i checked and yes that would be possible. but i found out that i can also make a breakout cable carrying the output of the mixer and a return channel, even easier. thanks for the tip though!

Comment: The output of the mixer isn't really MS though right? It's the post MS-matrix, no? Have never tried MS on an SQN though... SQN scares me.

Comment: haha! sqn scares you? why, i think it's a great machine and it sounds good to my ears.   
oh and yes it's a post ms-matrix if that means it doesn't sent an encoded signal to my recorder. 

Answer (score 0):

Hi man,
I feed my pcm with MS microphones but I could not find any MS Dematricer so I decided to buy my own according to some schematics I found on the net.
You will need to feed the MS dematricer box with the headphone Out of the PCM and plug your headphone on the output of the box. I just use it to monitor, not to record unmatriced.
I have been using that system for a bit more than a week and it works great. You don't need to be an expert in electronics to build it but the basics will help I guess.

Check that out:
http://www.recordingmag.com/resources/resourceDetail/326.html

Comment: hi, that looks good. i will check it out. for now i will settle with a slightly bulky multicable return channel monitoring. 

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't the SQN 4S allow you to monitor a matrixed signal in your headphones?  I'm pretty sure it does.  You also have the option of decoding your outputs as well.

this is the mixers I'm talking about:  http://www.sqn.co.uk/4SMspec.html

Is that the one you have?

Comment: Hi, i own the SQN 4S-iia. It's a golden oldie, with ms matrixing on headphones and return channels (via the multicable inputs). I don't have a manual, but i checked and didn't find an option to output in MS, which is actually ok. I want the discrete channels, so i can easily take just the M or enhance the width of the image (amount of S). This is a link with a picture of my SQN: http://www.sqn.co.uk/history2.html

Comment: I know that mixer well. My bro has that unit and I think it sounds way better than the current offerings from SQN..  Way better.